# issues with flask uploads

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-uploads

I'm working on a backend app which requires image uploads, I'm using flask-uploads but I have several issues, either by giving me syntax error for folder = f"user_{user_id}"
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

also for regex = f"^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_()-.]*.({allowed_format})$"

please help me how to solve it and let me know how to store the image path url into a database table of the user.

image helper code :

```
import os
import re
from typing import Union
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage



from flask_uploads import UploadSet, IMAGES

IMAGE_SET = UploadSet("images", IMAGES)  # set name and allowed extensions


def save_image(image, folder, name):
    return IMAGE_SET.save(image, folder, name)


def get_path(filename, folder):
    return IMAGE_SET.path(filename, folder)


def find_image_any_format(filename, folder):
    # """
    # Given a format-less filename, try to find the file by appending each of the allowed formats to the given
    # filename and check if the file exists
    # :param filename: formatless filename
    # :param folder: the relative folder in which to search
    # :return: the path of the image if exists, otherwise None
    # """
    for _format in IMAGES:  # look for existing avatar and delete it
        image = f"{filename}.{_format}"
        image_path = IMAGE_SET.path(filename=image, folder=folder)
        if os.path.isfile(image_path):
            return image_path
    return None


def _retrieve_filename(file):
    """
    Make our filename related functions generic, able to deal with FileStorage object as well as filename str.
    """
    if isinstance(file, FileStorage):
        return file.filename
    return file


def is_filename_safe(file):
    """
    Check if a filename is secure according to our definition
    - starts with a-z A-Z 0-9 at least one time
    - only contains a-z A-Z 0-9 and _().-
    - followed by a dot (.) and a allowed_format at the end
    """
    filename = _retrieve_filename(file)

    allowed_format = "|".join(IMAGES)
    # format IMAGES into regex, eg: ('jpeg','png') --> 'jpeg|png'
    regex = f"^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_()-\.]*\.({allowed_format})$"
    return re.match(regex, filename) is not None


def get_basename(file):
    """
    Return file's basename, for example
    get_basename('some/folder/image.jpg') returns 'image.jpg'
    """
    filename = _retrieve_filename(file)
    return os.path.split(filename)[1]


def get_extension(file):
    """
    Return file's extension, for example
    get_extension('image.jpg') returns '.jpg'
    """
    filename = _retrieve_filename(file)
    return os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
```

image resource code :

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask_uploads import UploadNotAllowed
from flask import send_file, request
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required, get_jwt_identity
import traceback
import os

from libs import image_helper

from schemas.image import ImageSchema

image_schema = ImageSchema()


class ImageUpload(Resource):
    @jwt_required
    def post(self):
        # """
        # This endpoint is used to upload an image file. It uses the
        # JWT to retrieve user information and save the image in the user's folder.
        # If a file with the same name exists in the user's folder, name conflicts
        # will be automatically resolved by appending a underscore and a smallest
        # unused integer. (eg. filename.png to filename_1.png).
        # """
        data = image_schema.load(request.files)
        user_id = get_jwt_identity()
        folder = f"user_{user_id}"
        try:
            # save(self, storage, folder=None, name=None)
            image_path = image_helper.save_image(data[0], folder=folder)
            # here we only return the basename of the image and hide the internal folder structure from our user
            basename = image_helper.get_basename(image_path)
            return {"message": ("image_uploaded").format(basename)}, 201
        except UploadNotAllowed:  # forbidden file type
            extension = image_helper.get_extension(data["image"])
            return {"message": ("image_illegal_extension").format(extension)}, 400


class Image(Resource):
    @jwt_required
    def get(self, filename):
        # """
        # This endpoint returns the requested image if exists. It will use JWT to
        # retrieve user information and look for the image inside the user's folder.
        # """
        user_id = get_jwt_identity()
        folder = f"user_{user_id}"
        # check if filename is URL secure
        if not image_helper.is_filename_safe(filename):
            return {"message": ("image_illegal_file_name").format(filename)}, 400
        try:
            # try to send the requested file to the user with status code 200
            return send_file(image_helper.get_path(filename, folder=folder))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return {"message": ("image_not_found").format(filename)}, 404

    @jwt_required
    def delete(self, filename):
        # """
        # This endpoint is used to delete the requested image under the user's folder.
        # It uses the JWT to retrieve user information.
        # """
        user_id = get_jwt_identity()
        folder = f"user_{user_id}"

        # check if filename is URL secure
        if not image_helper.is_filename_safe(filename):
            return {"message": ("image_illegal_file_name").format(filename)}, 400

        try:
            os.remove(image_helper.get_path(filename, folder=folder))
            return {"message": ("image_deleted").format(filename)}, 200
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return {"message": ("image_not_found").format(filename)}, 404
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return {"message": ("image_delete_failed")}, 500
```

image schema :

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

# from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
# from werkzeug.datastructures import  FileStorage

class FileStorageField(fields.Field):
    default_error_messages = {
        "invalid": "Not a valid image."
    }

    def _deserialize(self, value, attr, data):
        if value is None:
            return None

        if not isinstance(value, FileStorage):
            self.fail("invalid")

        return value


class ImageSchema(Schema):
    image = FileStorageField(required=True)
```

Comment: Please show the complete error messages you get. Update the above question, and properly format the error messages as code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 f"user_{user_id}"
```

This code is using the new Python 3.6 syntax, called f-strings.

This is a syntax error if you use a Python version smaller than 3.6.

Please also see:

https://github.com/jugmac00/python-version-cheat-sheet